# I am trying to insert a string character to another string. How can I achieve it in java?

Tags: java, join

This is the code I am working upon. I dont know where I am going wrong.

```
package mcdcpairwise;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Permutation
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String a="000";
        String b="|&";

        for (int i=0; i < a.length(); i++){
            if (i % 2 != 0){
                a = a.substring(0,i-1) + b.substring(0,i-1). + a.substring(i, a.length()) + b.substring(i, b.length());
                System.out.println(a);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The error I am facing is:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   String index out of range: -2     at
>   java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1967)  at
>   mcdcpairwise.Permutation.main(Permutation.java:13)

The output should be :

> 0|0&0

Comment: The code you posted produces `&00` as the output for me, which is what it looks like it should... `b` and `|` is never used.

Comment: while using b I was facing errors.So I tried taking & to do

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537174/putting-char-into-a-java-string-for-each-n-characters#537185 - Check the answers there; they may help.

Comment: I think the first `a.substring(0,i-1)` should be `a.substring(0,i)`

Comment: Welcome to SO. The code posted does not produce the error. You are trying to add `"&"`  to the string, so why do you expect the out put to be `0|0|0` ?  Also from the output you see that the loop runs once only.

Comment: @Zephyr that method is working for strings. It says Integers cannot be de-referenced. Is there any method that it would work for Integers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - StringIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19670369/java-stringindexoutofboundsexception)

Comment: @AxelH [ link ] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19670369/java-stringindexoutofboundsexception ) is not what I am looking for

Comment: Nah, but this would help you solved the exception you got at one point :`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: You need to be more clear here. How do you want to determine which character is to be inserted where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't clear from your question exactly what your "rules" are for processing this. However, your output seems to simply insert a character between each character of your source `a` string.

Instead of using a substring, create a separate `StringBuilder` to add individual characters to. The code below produces the output you are looking for:

```
String string = "000";
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {

    // Get current character in the string
    char c = string.charAt(i);

    // Add the current character to the output
    output.append(c);

    // If more characters exist, add the pipe
    if (i != string.length() - 1) {
        output.append("|");
    }
}

System.out.println(output.toString());
```

Comment: But the idea is not to insert `|` between each characters. If `b = "/\\"` this should output `0/0\0` based on the question...

Comment: Yeah, that is not at all clear in the question. Nowhere in the question is that explained...

Comment: My question ? Check again ;-) Just a hint, OP name is in a gray rectangle in the comments -> [`Averty micc`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9894389/averty-micc)

Comment: I edited my comment; definitely assumed you were the OP since you claim the question says something it doesn't say. :P

Comment: @AxelH your actuallly right. I am trying to insert ant type of character into a string. I will specify now. Sorry for the confusions. Any idea how it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

The right code should be `a.substring(0,i)`.

Comment: Just `a.substring(0,i)`? That's a short code to merge two `String` ! See [answer] please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.toCharArray` to get a `char[]` from a `String`. That way we can iterate more easily both `String` using an index.

```
String a="000";
String b="|&";

char[] arrayA = a.toCharArray();
char[] arrayB = b.toCharArray();
```

Then, all we have to do is to merge two array (from `String`s) taking one character from both. Adding two conditions (one per array)  to prevent any ArrayIndexOutOfBOundsException, we can insure we will merge two arrays.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

//Add a char from both array (until we reach on of the limit)
int i = 0;
while( i < arrayA.length && i < arrayB.length){
    sb.append(arrayA[i]).append(arrayB[i]);
    ++i;
}
```

Then we just need to add the remaining characters using a `for` loop on both arrays. Only one of those loop will be triggered (or none) since at least one previous condition (`i < arrayA.length && i < arrayB.length`) is already `false`.

```
//Add the rest of `a` if any
for(int j = i; j < arrayA.length; ++j){
    sb.append(arrayA[j]);
}

//Add the rest of `b` if any
for(int j = i; j < arrayB.length; ++j){
    sb.append(arrayB[j]);
}

System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

> 0|0&0

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a one line solution:

```
System.out.println((a + b).replaceAll("(?<=.)(?=.{" + (a.length() - 1) + "}(.))|.(?=.{0," + (b.length() - 1) + "}$)", "$1"));
```

This works with all combinations of non-blank starting strings.

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/MFMEne).